# Multicast works only in promiscuous mode

Tags: linux-networking, udp, multicast, igmp, promiscuous

I'm trying to receive MPEG-TS over UDP multicast transport in *Arch Linux*.

So when I run `ffprobe -i udp://@224.1.1.240:6000` it hangs forever with no result. Then I run `tcpdump` and it shows no multicast traffic from the address.

But if there is running `tcpdump -i eth0 -n net 224.0.0.0/4` in background while `ffprobe`, it works! tcpdump shows packets and ffprobe correctly detects a stream.

As one may notice the problem likely dissappears while NIC is in *promiscuous mode*.

Can someone help with it? What's wrong with my config?

- Everything in `iptables` is ACCEPTed.
- `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/*/rp_filter
  0
  0
  0
  0
  0
  0
  0`
- `ip r
  default dev ppp0  scope link
  83.221.214.192 dev ppp0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.7.248.143
  192.168.168.192/28 dev enp3s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.168.193
  224.0.0.0/4 dev enp3s0  scope link`

Network connected to ISP through D-LINK DGS-1005A.

PS Everything works perfect in Windows 7 on the same PC.

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is old, but...
it was necessary to set the allmulti flag on your network card

```
ifconfig enp3s0 allmulti
```